# Way to get VS2015 to validate for earlier syntax of C# to maintain compat with VS2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

A specific problem I'm running into is that VS2015 allows you to use newer C# syntax, e.g. `public string MyProperty => _myProperty;` when targeting a .NET 4.0 framework project and then others opening the project in VS2013 get compiler errors.

Is there a way to configure VS2015 so that it warns or errors on features specific to C# 6?  Or said another way, can I tell VS2015 which version of C# I'd like to compile against?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, but this needs to be done on a per-project basis.  It's an option available in the Build menu of the project properties.  Click "Advanced" in the bottom right, then select the language version you want.

[image]

Note: There is a VS2015 bug (which has been fixed in Update 1) that causes false negatives on get-only auto-properties.  To get the best results, make sure you have installed the latest update.

Comment: Perfect!  Now if only that option worked properly!  It caught `public string MyProp => myProp;` but didn't catch `public string MyProp2 { get; }`

Comment: I had noticed that as well; however, they seem to have fixed this problem in Visual Studio 2015 Update 1.

Comment: w00t.  Thanks.  I'll be sure to update it.  Just waiting for the timer to mark yours as the answer...

Answer (score 1):

To piggyback on the accepted answer, to quickly implement this in 100's of projects, and to get all configurations and not just a specific configuration, I mass edited the `csproj` files and inserted a `<LangVersion>5</LangVersion>` node as the first child inside the first naked, unconditional `<PropertyGroup>` node:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <LangVersion>5</LangVersion>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
```